# Is it possible to render controls inside controls in XNA?

Tags: xna, sprites, rendering

I want to know if there is an easy way to render sprites in XNA inside other sprites or something similar (I don't know if sprite is the best or unique way to draw in XNA). For example, I want to draw an object called SCENE that defines a rectangle. Inside the rectangle there are some SQUARES. I'd like to code something to draw all the SQUARES when the SCENE are draw. At the same time, if I draw the SQUARES on the SCENE, the movement of the SQUARES are limited by the SCENE size.

Is this possible in XNA?

I did this with Pygame and is very easy to make.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?  You can make a bunch of objects with `Draw(Spritebatch)` calls and it should work (I did something similar).

Comment: I want to have a SCENE with Controls variable that stores all the items of the SCENE.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx  look at third overload.  Will help you do what you described.

Comment: XNA lets you draw anything anywhere at any time, so the literal answer to your question is "yes".  But since that isn't useful, perhaps you should rephrase your question to help us determine what kind of answer you are really interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you would do this would be to use the power of C# and create some objects.

You would create a Scene object, that would have a Square object, which internally would have a collection of Squares inside it.

The `.Draw()` method of Scene would know it had to draw its own background, as well as tell the Square object to draw itself and all its children.

This is relatively easy with C#, extremely common, and probably the most simple way to do what you just mentioned in your post. A quick sample you might start with:

```
public class Scene 
{
    public Texture2D background;
    public SquareList Square;

    public class SquareList : List<Square>
    {
        List<Square> Items;
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch) 
        {
            foreach(var item in items) 
            {
                // store position of each item instead of hardcode
                batch.Draw(item, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White); 
            }
        }
    }
    public class Square
    {
        Texture2D myTexture;
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch) 
    {
        batch.Draw(background, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White);
        Square.Draw(batch);
    }
}
```

In this case, containment seems to make the most since, but you may want to have some of your objects inherit from a common base, such as "Sprite" or similar. It is beyond the scope of a single answer on this site to explain all of that. I recommend that you review some of the XNA sample code and see how they do things, and come back and ask us specific questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he wants is viewports ...

try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313965.aspx

Comment: I have to test this but I think is what I'm looking for. Let me check this out. Thanks.